# Hypothesis testing for a fixed constant (i.e. different intercept for a single observation)

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression

Given the following model: $\underline{Y}=X\underline{\beta}+\underline{\delta}+\underline{\epsilon}$

Where underlined terms are vectors and $\underline{\delta}=(\delta_1\quad 0\; \dots \;0)_{n\times1}^{'}$

I am trying to construct a test statistic for $\delta_1$, a scalar, such that $H_0:\delta_1=0$

My attempt, which involves reformulating the original equation, is as follows:

Let $X^*=\left( \begin{array}{cccc:c}
1 & x_{11} & \dots & x_{k1} & 1\\
1 & \vdots & \dots & \vdots & \vdots\\
1 & x_{1n} & \dots & x_{kn} & 0\\
\end{array}\right)$ $\quad$ and $\quad$ $\beta^*=\left( \begin{array}{c}
\underline{\beta}\\
\delta_1\\
\end{array}\right)_{(k+2)\times 1}$

then construct the test statistic as:

$\frac{(C\hat{\underline{\beta}}^*)^{'}[C(X^{*'}X^{*})^{-1}C^{'}]^{-1}(C\hat{\underline{\beta}}^*)}{(\underline{Y}-X^*\hat{\underline{\beta}}^*)^{'}(\underline{Y}-X^*\hat{\underline{\beta}}^*)/n-k-2}$ $\quad$ where $\quad$ $C=(\underline{0}_{k+1}\quad 1)$

Would this be a valid test statistic for the desired hypothesis? If not, what would be?

Comment: This looks like the $F$-test for your null, so yes

Comment: See the "event study" tests in econometrics. The proposed test is one of them, and it is a standard type of test. It also generalizes easily to multiple dependent variables.  One thing to be aware of is that the test essentially just compares the residual at the first observation (assuming a model without the $\delta$) with the normal distribution.  Hence the test is quite sensitive to the normality assumption. This can be overcome by appropriate bootstrap sampling; see Journal of Financial Econometrics, Volume 2, Issue 3, June 2004, Pages 451–471.